# Python Regex: Find all caps with no following lowercase

Tags: python, regex

How can I retain all capital characters, given that subsequent characters are not lower case?

Consider this example:

```
import re
test1 = 'ThisIsATestTHISISATestTHISISATEST'

re.findall(r'[A-Z]{2}[^a-z]+', test1)
# ['THISISAT', 'THISISATEST']
```

**Expectation**:
This: `'THISISAT'`, should read: `'THISISA'`

Comment: can you provide more examples?

Comment: Why (in simple pattern terms) shouldn't the final capital of 'THISISAT' be matched, whereas the final capital of 'THISISATEST' should? What are the precise criteria?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try ([regex101](https://regex101.com/r/zp8J14/1)):

```py
import re

test1 = "ThisIsATestTHISISATestTHISISATEST"

print(re.findall(r"[A-Z]{2}[A-Z]*(?![a-z])", test1))
```

Prints:

```py
['THISISA', 'THISISATEST']
```

Comment: `[A-Z]{2}[A-Z]*` -> ``[A-Z]{2,}``